# Display text in a string based on boolean value

Tags: c#, winforms

This is the line causing the issue:

`lblClimberInfo.Text = selectedClimber + "\r\n" + "Finished: " + selectedClimber.HasFinished ? "Yes" : "DNF" + "\r\n" + "Time: " + selectedClimber.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + selectedClimber.Minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + selectedClimber.Seconds.ToString("00");`

From my main class:

```
private bool hasFinished;

public bool HasFinished
{
    get { return hasFinished; }
    set { hasFinished = false; }
}
```

I want it so that it says `Finished: Yes` if the `HasFinished` bool is true and display `Finished: DNF` if the `HasFinished` bool is false and display that. At the minute, it displays `Finished: False` by default but when I click a button that runs a method that essentially changes the bool, instead of saying `Finished: True` it just says `Finished:`.

I want to be able to customise it instead of it outputting `True` or `False`

Comment: What exactly is "the issue"?

Answer (score 1):

Because of operator precedence issues, put parenthesis around ternary operators. Otherwise the "Time" will only show if `HasFinished` is false.

```
lblClimberInfo.Text = selectedClimber + "\r\n" + "Finished: " + (selectedClimber.HasFinished ? 
  "Yes" : "DNF") + "\r\n" + "Time: " + selectedClimber.Hours.ToString("00") + ":" + 
  selectedClimber.Minutes.ToString("00") + ":" + selectedClimber.Seconds.ToString("00");
```

Also, your setter is quite interesting:

```
private bool hasFinished;

public bool HasFinished
{
    get { return hasFinished; }
    set { hasFinished = false; }
}
```

It seems like it is impossible for HasFinished to be true, unless you modify the private variable somewhere else in your class. But instead of having a setter that sets the property to false always, it is better to omit the setter and thus making the property read-only. You might want to read up on [Using Properties in C#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w86s7x04.aspx)

To define a correct setter, use this instead:

```
    set { hasFinished = value; }
```

Comment: Hmm, it's emitting some strange behaviour. When I run the program and select a climber, the time for each climber is automatically set to 00:00:00, so it says `Finished: DNF`, but when I select another climber and then go back to the previous one, it says DNF even if the time isn't 00:00:00.

Comment: I have code in another class called `Gate.cs` that does this: `public void ProcessClimber(Climber selectedClimber)
        {
            total += selectedClimber.HasFinished ? 0 : 1;
            selectedClimber.HasFinished = true;
        }`

Comment: @user2929108 Because you are using `HasFinished` with capital `H`, your are using the property setter there which sets it to false with the setter you have. See my updated answer for a solution.

Comment: This is going to sound weird, but I literally found and fixed the mistake about 3 or 4 seconds before I saw your comment!

Comment: @user2929108 I still think you should read up on "Using Properties in C#" (link in answer).